# Why am I getting socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] from Python HTTPLib

Tags: python, linux, sockets

My Python code is very simple, make a GET request on a webpage created on an Arduino Yún.

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("yun.local")
conn.request("GET", "/arduino/read/temp/0")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason, r1.read()
```

When I run this on the Linux side of the Arduino Yún, the following error shows up *socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known*. However, when I run the same script on my Mac, it just works fine.

I overcome this problem by changing the HTTPConnection argument to *httplib.HTTPConnection("192.168.240.1")*, which is the IP from the Arduino Yun.

So, why is this error showing up on the Linux side of Arduino and not in my Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the `yun.local` is configured in the `/etc/hosts` on the Arduino?...

Comment: The only thing inside that file is"127.0.0.1 localhost"

Comment: So `yun.local` does not exist on your Linux distrib. Hence the error. Try to `ping yun.local` via SSH, you will see the same problem. Add `192.168.240.1 yun.local` and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MaximeLorant. Also, I checked the same file on my Mac and the content is the same. Why would that error not show up when I run the script on my Mac?

Answer (score 16):

The `socket.gaierror` comes from Python not being able to run `getaddrinfo()` or `getnameinfo()`. In your case it is likely the first one. That function takes a host and a port and returns a list of tuples with information about how to connect to a host. If you give a host name to that function there will be a try to resolve the IP address deeper below.

So, the error should come from Python not being able to resolve the address you have written (`yun.local`) to a valid IP address. I would suggest you look in `/etc/hosts` on the device to see if it is defined there. You can also try with command line tools such as `host` or `telnet`, just to check the resolving:

For example:

```
[pugo@q-bert ~]$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

There it managed to resolve my `localhost` to `::1` (IPv6) and `127.0.0.1` (IPv4), because it exists in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If I instead try with your host:

```
[pugo@q-bert ~]$ telnet yun.local 80
telnet: could not resolve yun.local/80: Name or service not known
```

Comment: I can understand better how the error comes to be. I have checked both "/etc/resolv.conf" and "/etc/hosts" on my Mac and my Linux and the content in both is the same. So I still don't get why would the error shows up on the Linux and not in the Mac.

Comment: By saying that the error don't show up, do you mean that the Python code works if you run it on your Mac? What I am fishing for is whether it is just a difference in error reporting or if it really succeeds finding the IP address for the `yun.local` there in some magic way. Most of the network functionality in Python maps down to system functions. System differences can cause different behavior on error conditions.

Comment: Yes, the Python interpreter in my Mac finds the IP address for `yun.local` but the Python interpreter in the Linux does not find the IP address for `yun.local`. So you are probably right, there must be some system differences that could cause the different behaviour.

Comment: The idea is that by using `yun.local`I do not have to care about the IP address. Otherwise, I need to setup a static IP address for the device.

Comment: I am unfortunately too little of a Mac user to know why your Mac can find the IP for that host. Now I am just guessing: have you run any development tool for the device on your Mac that can have changed system functionality so that the system knows that host and IP?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on a linux machine(Centos7).
I have already included yun.local in the /etc/hosts file.
FYI,
`[root@localhost orchestration]# telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@localhost orchestration]#
[root@localhost orchestration]#
[root@localhost orchestration]# telnet yun.local 80
Trying 192.168.240.1...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.240.1: Connection refused`
Could you suggest something??

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the hostname. So I realized the /etc/hosts remained the old hostname, I just updated to the new hostname in the /etc/hosts file and that worked for me.