# succeed in script but fail in rc.local

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, rc

I write mail.py(use webpy) to send me the ip address of each machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
#coding=utf-8

import web  
def send_mail(send_to, subject, body, cc=None, bcc=None):  
    try:  
        web.config.smtp_server = 'xxxxx'   
        web.config.smtp_port = 25    
        web.config.smtp_username = 'xxx'  
        web.config.smtp_password = 'xxx'   
        web.config.smtp_starttls = True  
        send_from = 'xxx'    

        web.sendmail(send_from, send_to, subject, body, cc=cc, bcc=bcc)  
        return 1  #pass  
    except Exception, e:  
        print e  
        return -1 #fail  
if __name__=='__main__':  
    print "in mail.py"
    f=file('/home/spark/Desktop/ip.log') 
    f1=f.read()
    f.close()
    send_to = ['xxxx']          
    subject = 'xxxx'  
    body = 'ip:',f1 
    send_mail(send_to, subject, body)
```

rc.local

```
bash deploy.sh &
exit 0
```

deploy.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env
cd /home/spark/Desktop
python mail.py  >>deploy.log
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
```

I can receive email if I do 'python mail.py'.But when I put it in rc.local, I can not receive the email, the message in deploy.log outputs 
[Errno -2 ] Name or service not known.

I am puzzled with this output.

Comment: I changed web.config.smtp_server with the ip address instead of the domain_name and it worked. I think the error is because some configurations and services are not available during the rc.local process. Helpful links are [sendmail](https://wiki.list.org/DOC/Mail%20delivery%20fails%20with%20%22(-2,%20'Name%20or%20service%20not%20known')%22,%20aka%20I%20am%20not%20receiving%20any%20notification%20messages%20from%20Mail)
[unknown service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777121/why-am-i-getting-socket-gaierror-errno-2-from-python-httplib)

Comment: [tricks to debug rc.local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because `PATH` is different when `rc.local` runs. Specifically, `web.sendmail` might expect to find `sendmail` in the path, but it's not there yet. See docs [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sendmail).

The paths might be specific to your system. To debug this you could dump things from inside `rc.local` to a file such as `/tmp/rc.local.log` and inspect it when the system is up: e.g., `env >>/tmp/rc.local.log`.

Note, if you have multiple drives being mounted during startup, the drive containing `sendmail` might not be mounted yet at that point. This is a pain to deal with. To double check, add `mount >>/tmp/rc.local.log`.