# Name or service not known in python3.7

Tags: sockets, python-3.7

I have one of my existing test script that depends on a few Python libraries written in Python 2.7.

The libraries are mainly to establish few SMTP connectivity, sockets, etc and since being a newbie, I don't get what exactly they do. I was told to do an upgrade to Python 3.7 which is successful and after that when I run my scripts, I see the below error.

I am not sure what is causing this issue after upgrade. I have upgraded the relevant libraries as well.

Could you please help me to know what needs to be done to eliminate this socket error?

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtpd.py", line 646, in **init** type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
>   for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>   socket.gaierror:[Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the address you tying to access can not be resolved. You should check the host name or IP address as well as your networking/routing.

> This exception is raised for address-related errors, for getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo().

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777462/7204688